# Symfony get Oauth Token With Authorization code

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am having a hell of a time getting an Access token using OAuth 2.0

My site requests a Authorization code.. and redirects back to my page once its got it.. I then have those variables to use to send for an access token

Also I have tried to put the params in query instead of headers.. and same result

```
$response = $httpClient->request('POST', $tokenURL, [
  'headers' => [
    'code' => $_GET['code'],
    'client_id' => 'CLIENT ID',
    'client_secret' => 'CLIENT SECRET',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/connect',
  ],
]);
```

I have this requests linked to a button. so when I press the button it will send the request off...

Im getting 400 Response, and I have no idea what I am missing!

Comment: Where does the 400 come from oauth server or yours? What oauth server are you using?

Comment: 400 comes from oauth, 

https://docs.vendhq.com/reference/introduction/authorization#oauth-20

is what im using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a request to the token endpoint you should be sending the parameters in the body of the request, like a form. Currently you send them in headers, which is not right. Also make sure what is the correct way of authenticating the client when making a call to the token endpoint. You might have to send an `Authorization` header with `Basic` authentication.

So your request might look like this:

```php
$response = $httpClient->request('POST', $tokenURL, [
  'body' => [
    'code' => $_GET['code'],
    'client_id' => 'CLIENT ID',
    'client_secret' => 'CLIENT SECRET',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/connect',
  ],
]);
```

or maybe like this:

```php
$response = $httpClient->request('POST', $tokenURL, [
  'headers' => [
    'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode('CLIENT ID:CLIENT SECRET')
  ],
  'body' => [
    'code' => $_GET['code'],
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/connect',
  ],
]);
```

Comment: Having everything in the 'body' was correct. I tested it out with Postman, 

on my web app I have it working where it doesn't give me an error. but I can't seem to find the date.. I tried to var_dump($response) and the data isn't there :( 

Thanks again for all your help!

Now im just having trouble on getting

Comment: You should call `$response->getContent()` to get the data associated with the response. You have other methods on the response object, to check the status code, etc. Check the documentation of HttpClient to know how to work with it: https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html

Comment: Worked Perfectly!!!! 

Thank you so much, I totally missed that part... shame on me.. because 40 lines down.. I had another api call ... and clearly used getContent().. 

Thanks for your help!!!!